# How to fetch status column based on max/min of a timestamp column

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this

| Emplid | REQUEST_ID | Status | Status_Dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | Open | 02-Jun-2022 12.35.00.AM |
| 1231 | 5 | Draft | 02-Jun-2022 12.30.00.AM |
| 1234 | 1 | In Progress | 02-Jun-2022 12.47.00.AM |

How can I get **request date** as `Min(Status Dttm)` and **current status** as `Max(Status Dttm)` of every request

I tried using this
`SELECT EMPLID,REQUEST_ID,MIN(Status_Dttm) AS "REQUEST DATE", (SELECT STATUS FROM STS_TBL WHERE MAX(Status_Dttm)) AS "CURRENT_STATUS" FROM STS_TBL;`

getting error as "Group function is not allowed here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add `GROUP BY request_id` if you want to group by each request:

```sql
SELECT MIN(emplid) AS emplid,
       request_id,
       MIN(status_dttm) AS request_date,
       MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY status_dttm) AS current_status 
FROM   sts_tbl
GROUP BY request_id
```

Which outputs:

> | EMPLID | REQUEST_ID | REQUEST_DATE | CURRENT_STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | 1 | 2022-06-02 00:35:00 | In Progress |
> | 1231 | 5 | 2022-06-02 00:30:00 | Draft |

---

If the `request_id` is the same for each `emplid` (which appears to be the case for your sample data) then you could use:

```sql
SELECT emplid,
       MIN(status_dttm) AS request_date,
       MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY status_dttm) AS current_status 
FROM   sts_tbl
GROUP BY emplid
```

Which outputs:

> | EMPLID | REQUEST_DATE | CURRENT_STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1231 | 2022-06-02 00:30:00 | Draft |
> | 1234 | 2022-06-02 00:35:00 | In Progress |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=491939a01c71509af0965b39dc0b049b)*

Comment: Thsnkd @Mt0 it worked

Comment: is it possible to add few more columns to the view, like No_of_Days_in_New will show sysdate-REQUEST_DATE In_progress_since will show the date for in progress requests and completed date will show if the request status in completed then that date